# API Gateway POST request returning null with POSTMAN

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to add data into Neo4j. I have integrated my lambda function with a POST API in the API Gateway.

```html
public class App implements RequestHandler<Map<Object,Object>, Object> {

    public Object handleRequest(Map<Object,Object> input, Context context) {

        try (Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(Config.url, AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"))) {

            try (Session session = driver.session()) {
                String id = (String)input.get("id");
                System.out.println(id);
                Result result = session.run("CREATE (n:Id {id: $id})",Values.parameters("id", id));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I give json input through Lambda Test Event- {"id":"1"}
it works but the same with Postman is returning a null value.

The data is getting uploaded to neo4j but no "id"